# CORS error after deployment on render.com

Tags: cors, mern, render.com

Frontend is not working because of CORS error. I m deploying my frontend on Netlify and Backend on Render.com.

I've deployed backend of my app on render.com.

## index.mjs:

```
const app=express();
app.use('/uploads',express.static(__dirname+'/uploads'))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(cors({
credentials:true
 }))
app.use(express.json())
```

The **URl** of deployed backend is being used as **BASE_URL** in my frontend React App

```
axios.defaults.baseURL =BASE_URL;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; //to set cookies in browser
```

So, I have to deploy my backend first so that i can setup the BASE_URL in my frontend app but when i deployed my frontend on Netlify, I got CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mernchatappbackend- 
ilmz.onrender.com/profile' from origin 
'https://650dafee1e4e28138cbe9398--resilient-druid- 
912e90.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of 
the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not 
 be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 
'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the 
 XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
 mernchatappbackend-ilmz.onrender.com/profile:1     
 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Can anyone help me out with this?
As there's no way i could specify the frontend's origin in cors option in backend.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

## You could implement the security problem you want like this

See [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options).

The `origin` option can take a function.

```
(request, callback) => {
    const error = null;
    const allowed_origin = req.headers.origin ?? '*'; // If there is no origin this value doesn't really matter
    callback(error, allowed_origin);
}
```

## Why you shouldn't do that

Your request is coming with credentials, by allowing any origin you make it very easy for CSRF attack to be performed.

1. User visits your site
2. User logs into your API and gets credentials
3. User visits malicious site
4. Malicious site makes Ajax request to your API and the browser sends credentials

Normally CORS would stop that attack dead in its tracks, but you are allowing any origin to make a credentialed request to your API.

## Instead

> As there's no way i could specify the frontend's origin in cors option in backend.

You need to fix this. You have to know which origins you can trust. If Netlify don't give you a means to know what hostname your site will have in advance, then find a different host.

Comment: You write: _CORS would stop that attack_. No; [CORS is not, and never was, a defense](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/948831079649169408). You surely meant the SOP, not CORS.